Unable to handle HttpStatusCodeException as it is not throws
I have to call an API endpoint - $apiUrl/api/users which when,

successfully creates users - returns OK with 200
user already exists - returns CONFLICT with 409
...and some different 4xx statuses

Assume the above API works fine per above scenarios.
However, when there is 4xx errors from the above endpoint, the HttpStatusCodeException is never caught on the below code and always reaches the general Exception. It uses Spring RestOperations for the POST operation.
override fun signup(request: SignupRequest, token: String): SignupResponse {
    val headers = HttpHeaders()
    headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
    headers.setBearerAuth(token)

    val entity = HttpEntity(request, headers)

    try {
        return restClient.postForObject("$apiUrl/api/users", entity, SignupResponse::class.java)!!
    } catch (e: HttpStatusCodeException) {
        throw APIException(readError(e)) // never reaches here so I can throw custom exception
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw UnauthorizedException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) // always reaches here
    }
}

I get the e: Exception below says the error response structure is different but it should have reached the HttpStatusCodeException to better handle it right???
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:     
Instantiation of [simple type, class      
com.xxxxxxx.signup.SignupResponse] value failed for JSON property 
user_id due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter user_id which is a non-
nullable type

SignupResponse.kt is,
data class SignupResponse(
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    val user_id: String,
)

Further debugging gave me an info that it checks for hasError() with list of configurable httpErrors but couldn't find how to configure.
Also tried having a custom error handler but never reaches the hasError()
class CustomResponseErrorHandler : ResponseErrorHandler {
    override fun hasError(...) { }
}

I might be missing something else too but thanks in advance for your help!

Not sure if that is the exception that is being thrown, catch RestClientException instead and check which type it is. However looking at your error you are getting a HttpMessageNotReadableException which will result in a generic error because you cannot parse the result. So apparently something else is happening or you aren't getting the result you think you get.

I agree with @m-deinum catch that exception is not related with restTemplate errors. Instead, try to make SignupResponse#user_id's type nullable and check. I believe "$apiUrl/api/users" API does not provide you with expected data.
May be it's better to receive response as Map<String, Object> and then construct SignupResponse.
